# Automatic wrapping to new line?

Tags: wrapping, line-breaks

Instead of wrapping lines visually, I want vim to wrap with a linebreak regardless of my the window dimensions. How can I set this automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work with `wrapmargin`:

```
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=1
set formatoptions+=t
set formatoptions-=l
```

The option `wrapmargin` defines the *number of characters from the right window border where wrapping starts*. This option is only used, if `textwidth` is set to zero.

The `formatoptions` flag `t` enables auto-wrap of text. By removing `l` from `formatoptions`, also lines that are already longer are wrapped.

See  `:help 'wrapmargin'`, `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help fo-table`

Comment: "... regardless of my window dimensions." -- from the description of `wrapmargin` it is kind of the opposite. But I didn't know about it, thx.

Comment: @MaximKim Guess the question has room for interpretation. We'll see what the TO meant, after he accepted an answer. :-)

Comment: I want it wraped using a linebreak. The problem is that it can feel difficult to tell where lines start and end when writing code, and it makes the find shortcut act strange.

Comment: @Hussar Set `wrapmargin` to `1`. Guess made some mistake while testing.

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
set textwidth=50
```

> The 'textwidth' option can be used to automatically break a line
>   before it gets too long.  Set the 'textwidth' option to the desired
>   maximum line length.  If you then type more characters (not spaces or
>   tabs), the last word will be put on a new line (unless it is the only
>   word on the line).  If you set 'textwidth' to 0, this feature is
>   disabled.
>
> ...
>
> The line is only broken automatically when using Insert mode, or when
>   appending to a line.  When in replace mode and the line length is not
>   changed, the line will not be broken.

**PS**

In the comments I see you use "auto" linebreaks for coding.

Have you tried `breakindent` and friends?

[image]

Comment: then setting textwidth requires that I change it each time the dimensions of the window change. Why can't this be done for me?

Comment: It can be, using `wrapmargin`. But it depends on window dimension which you said in the question you want to avoid (or I read it that way :). `textwidth` doesn't depend on window dimensions and will insert linebreak at the specified column.

Comment: I should have made that more clear. I suspected a solution like that would exist. Wouldn't this make each function behave like one long line and make it harder to move within the function?

Comment: Well, you don't have to put a whole function in one line. Breakindent helps visually break a line you don't want to automatically break physically(or hard) because it might change a semantic. Take a python for example, you are not allowed to break a line without adding special continuation char `\\`.